# How to "undo" History API's replaceState() when closing Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, html5-history

I'm using the History API's [replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) when a [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) is displayed, so the user can share, bookmark, etc. the URL when the page is in it's current state. When a user closes the modal, the URL still contains the query string `domain.com/page/?modal=url-friendly-name`.

I cannot seem to get the URL to return to just `domain.com/page/`. How can this be accomplished?

I believe whatever code is needed, should be inserted in the following event listener:

```
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
 // return URL back to domain.com/page/
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: rephrasing the question, does the link which is in the modal, user share it when modal remain open or share when modal closed?

Comment: @Shehary When a user shares or bookmarks the URL while viewing a modal, the modal will re-appear upon page load.

Comment: ok now, so the URL in the modal to bookmark is in this state `domain.com/page/?modal=url-friendly-name`

Comment: @Shehary That's correct. However, if the modal is closed, I need the URL to go back to just domain.com/page/.

Comment: I think this can help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript fetch link and split, with javascript or jQuery inside bootstrap hidden event listener